# container becomes undraggable when I switch to landscape orientation

Tags: ios, orientation, xcode8

I have build a layout in portait mode, which I am happy with. It consist of 3 elements: A map view that fills 1/3 of the screen, positioned at the top, a web view that fills 1/3 of the screen, positioned at the middle of the screen, and a container that also fills 1/3 of the screen, and is positioned at the bottom. Within that container there are two text containers.
As soon as I switch to landscape mode, to create a different layout with the 3 elements, the container becomes undraggable.

My end results is supposed to look like this: [image]

I'm working in xcode 8.

Hope someone knows whats going on.

Thanks

Comment: It's rather vague what you are asking. I'm presuming you are talking about dragging the view in Xcode's IB tool. Perhaps some screen dumps or even a link to a video might help explain your problem better.

Comment: Here's a link to a video that shows what I mean. https://vimeo.com/206838777